# Springboot 2.7.4 cannot connect to Postgres DB with sslmode=require

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc

I am using springboot 2.7.4 when I try to connect to Postgres db on azure I met the error

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: FIPS cipher suites are enforced for this >server. Please specify FIPS complying cipher suites in your SSL/TLS settings.

How can we specify the FIPS cipher suites? I see other projects using springboot 2.5.x, they do not seem to have any issues

Answer (score 0):

Verify your dependencies version which are compatible with spring-boot version 2.7.4.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.4/reference/html/dependency-versions.html#appendix.dependency-versions

Comment: Its not working. Same error. I am using containers to deploy so I'm actually using custom jre which I reference from
https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/

Could it be modules missing from jre ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by removing custom JRE reference from https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/

It might be because some modules are not added properly when using jlink to create custom jre